# Import .obj and .mtl files in Webots using a PROTO file

Tags: webots

I am trying to import a .obj with a .mtl linked to it. When importing it using the 'Import 3D Model' option, everything works perfectly, the material is well kept:
[image: First image]

But when I try to import it from a PROTO file, the material is not added, and the model is basically all one color:
[image: Second image]
[image: Proto file]

Any idea on how to be able to add a .obj and its corresponding .mtl from a PROTO file, so that the texture and faceset coordinates are not described into it (for better readability, as the model is pretty big)?

Comment: Could you please share your .obj and .mtl files?

Comment: Sure! Here they are:
[Obj file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OYMJWIPd2OAn7TblqMRhgq2DRdtkVZZj/view?usp=sharing)
[Mtl file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1c0A1cagpa6qeTq_-3Scsa0zJLx-n-t4j/view?usp=sharing)
@OlivierMichel